# How to fix django-oscar shipping UnboundLocalError?

Tags: django, django-oscar

I want to add a shipping methods to django-oscar, but I'm getting the UnboundLocalError error even though I've done everything on the document page.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/shipping-address/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    
local variable 'methods' referenced before assignment
```

**repository.py**

```
from oscar.apps.shipping import repository
from . import methods

class Repository(repository.Repository):

    def get_available_shipping_methods(self, basket, user=None, shipping_addr=None, request=None, **kwargs):
        methods = (methods.Standard(),)
        if shipping_addr and shipping_addr.country.code == 'GB':
            # Express is only available in the UK
            methods = (methods.Standard(), methods.Express())
        return methods
```

**methods.py**

```
from oscar.apps.shipping import methods
from oscar.core import prices
from decimal import Decimal as D

class Standard(methods.Base):
    code = 'standard'
    name = 'Shipping (Standard)'

    def calculate(self, basket):
        return prices.Price(
            currency=basket.currency,
            excl_tax=D('5.00'), incl_tax=D('5.00'))

class Express(methods.Base):
    code = 'express'
    name = 'Shipping (Express)'

    def calculate(self, basket):
        return prices.Price(
            currency=basket.currency,
            excl_tax=D('4.00'), incl_tax=D('4.00'))
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: You are reusing the same variable `methods` as a global & as a local variable inside `repository.Repository.get_available_shipping_methods`. You should rather use a different variable name for the return variable or import with `as`. The error you see is because the imported `methods` module becomes reassigned as a `tuple`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that is in the docs, but they look to have a bug in them.

With `UnboundLocalError` you're essentially looking at a scope issue. A really simple example would be;

```
x = 10
def foo():
    x += 1
    print x
foo()
```

When `foo` executes x isn't available to `foo`. So change the import slightly to avoid this;

```
from oscar.apps.shipping import repository
from . import methods as shipping_methods

class Repository(repository.Repository):

    def get_available_shipping_methods(self, basket, user=None, shipping_addr=None, request=None, **kwargs):
        methods = (shipping_methods.Standard(),)
        if shipping_addr and shipping_addr.country.code == 'GB':
            # Express is only available in the UK
            methods = (shipping_methods.Standard(), shipping_methods.Express())
        return methods
```

Comment: It's the very nice solution. Thanks so much.